# Can't redirect webpage when I try to run the function 'biblioshiny()' with the R package 'bibliometrix'

Tags: r

I try to use 'bibliometrix' package to realize the visualization of published papers, and When I try to install the package and library the package is all successful, but when I run the function 'biblioshiny()', it should jump the website in browser directly, but the website can't open.

**The script in Console of R studio is following below:**

```
> biblioshiny()

Listening on http://127.0.0.1:3818
Warning: Error in actionBttn: unused argument (width = "100%")
  106: dots_list
  105: div
    2: runApp
    1: biblioshiny
Warning: Error in actionBttn: unused argument (width = "100%")
  106: dots_list
  105: div
    2: runApp
    1: biblioshiny
```

**The website result is like this:**

```
An error has occurred!

unused argument (width = "100%")
```

I guess the Internet work lead to this issue, so I close the VPN, but it still can't jump to the right website successfully.

Comment: I have the same error. I am using Windows11 with Rstudio 2023.06.1 with R 4.2.

Comment: Thanks for your comment here, I tried your way again and it works!  I updated R and Rstudio to the newest version, and R packages as well.@Daniele Marinho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem today, but the reason was that I hadn't used R for a long time, so everything was out of date. I updated Rbase, Rstudio, the shiny package and its dependencies, and then it worked normally.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35827088)